# Ember-data embedded records current state?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am really stuck with tons of problems caused by Ember-data and it lacks of embedded records support.

I have searched the entire web, most of the posts are outdated others are outdated + requires me to use 3rd party libraries or to wire up 300 lines of special code with lots of drawbacks.

I've no idea how to use embedded records with ember-data as it stands today?

**edit:** there is a new documentation now http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using the `ActiveModelSerializer` you can include the `EmbeddedRecordsMixin`  which allows you to use embedded records.  (In the canary versions, 1.0 beta 9+, you can use the `JsonSerializer`/`RESTSerializer` as well)

#### Serializer

```
App.ColorSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    foos: {embedded: 'always'}
  }
});
```

#### Models

```
App.Color = DS.Model.extend({
  color: DS.attr(),
  foos: DS.hasMany('foo')
});

App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr()
});
```

#### JSON

```
{
 colors:[
  {
    id: 1,
    color: "red",
    foos:[
      {
        id:1,
        name:'something 1'
      },
      {
        id:2,
        name:'something 2'
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qagalabaso/1/edit

For the `RESTSerializer` and `JsonSerializer` it follows the same pattern

```
App.ColorSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    foos: {embedded: 'always'}
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lesiwebobi/1/edit

Comment: Thanks @kingpin2k without you 90% of Ember questions would remain unanswered :), do i have to make a serilaizer for each model? or i can set some generic global embedded serilaizer

Comment: that's a great question, I'd imagine you could just do an ApplicationSerializer, and just list all of the types that are embedded in the `attrs` hash.

Comment: Excellent! I think that Ember docs totally miss all the embedded part

Comment: How can i make it work with the FixtureAdapter? seems like it bypass transformers and serializers

Comment: Yeha, unfortunately that mixin only works with the active model serializer, I believe it's planned to make it available for the rest serializer, but hasn't happened yet.  Additionally you can't use pushPayload to sideload the record.  Really the only working use case is the active model serializer, and data from the server (or mocked data)

Comment: I'm trying to use this for a belongsTo relationship but it's not working, is that possible?

Comment: Can you POST embedded records to the server?

Comment: Documentation is now up to date: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html

Comment: @Kingpin2k please setup same JSBIN example for `Ember: 1.12.1 & Ember Data: 1.13.4` - In this configuration I can't get embedded records working!

Comment: Are you sure those two versions are compatible?

Comment: any workaround to allow the use of RESTSerializer? I'm getting "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined".