# Value is showing up as [object Object] ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to set up the attributes to my model but having trouble when nesting objects.  Here is what I have

```
App.Posts = DS.Model.extend({
        title:  DS.attr('string'),
        author: {
            name:   DS.attr('string')
        },
        date:   DS.attr('date'),
        excerpt:    DS.attr('string'),
        body:   DS.attr('string')
    });
```

How am I suppose to declare the author object?

In the ember inspector when I go under data and under App.post and select one of the rows.  It has a property a property App.Post with an attribute author: { name: [Object] }

here is the JS Bin link http://jsbin.com/tesozepexaqi/2/

Comment: Are you really bent on using Ember Data?

Comment: I'm just trying to go through the tutorials.  Is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember works perfectly fine without Ember Data.  Let's pretend we want to do it with Ember Data:

Ember Data's Records should be flat.  This means all properties are at the top level.  If you have a related data that exist deeper they generally live in a different record.  If you're attempting to embed the record you'll need to look into the tricky world of embedded records ([Ember-data embedded records current state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222457/ember-data-embedded-records-current-state/24224682#24224682)). At the very least these related records must have an id defined.  So here's an example of what the data returned from server should look like.

```
  {
    posts:[
      {
        id: '1',
        title:  'My name is Django.',
        author: {
          id:1,
          name:   'D name'
        },
        date:   new Date('08-15-2014'),
        excerpt:    'The D is silent.',
        body:   'The D is silent.'
      }, 
      {
         id: '2',
         title:  'White horse',
         author: {
           id:2,
             name:   'horse name'
         },
         date:   new Date('08-15-2014'),
         excerpt:    'Is what I ride.',
         body:   'My horse likes to dance.'
     }
    ]
  }
```

#### Code

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend();


App.PostSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    author: {embedded: 'always'}
  }
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title:  DS.attr('string'),
  author: DS.belongsTo('author'),
  date:   DS.attr('date'),
  excerpt:    DS.attr('string'),
  body:   DS.attr('string')
});

App.Author = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr()
});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/vazada/1/edit

One other small tip, you'll not want to use globals when working with the routes, you can use `modelFor` to get the model from a different route.

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('post');
    }
});

App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
      var posts = this.modelFor('posts');
      return posts.findBy('id', params.post_id);
    }
});
```

Personally, I think Ember Data is overkill.  Ember works perfectly well with POJOs.  If you need caching and the ability to rollback then Ember Data might be a good solution for you.

Example: http://jsbin.com/vazada/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting [this example](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_one-to-one) from the Ember docs like the below should work:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title:  DS.attr('string'),
  author: DS.belongsTo('author'),
  date:   DS.attr('date'),
  excerpt:    DS.attr('string'),
  body:   DS.attr('string')
});

App.Author = DS.Model.extend({
  post: DS.belongsTo('post')
})
```

Comment: This didn't fix the problem.

Comment: You're going to need to share more information then like a jsbin demonstrating the issue or a code repository.  The issue may lie elsewhere in your code.