# Ember data EmbeddedRecordMixin

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I've been trying to make an embedded list of models get loaded. I understood from the demo that EmbeddedRecordsMixin was the way to go but this still fails with: "Error: Assertion Failed: TypeError: factory is undefined" I have tried to separate them in my fixtures and this works just fine so I must be missing something in the embedding part even though it follows this: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html

Does this doesn't work with Fixtures then?

```
var App = window.App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});
var attr = DS.attr;

App.Modificators = DS.Model.extend({
    "tpe": attr('string')
});
App.SpecialStuff = DS.Model.extend({
    "title": attr('string'),
    "body": attr('string'),
    "modificators": DS.hasMany('modificators')
});

App.SpecialStuffSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
        "modificators": { embedded: 'always' }
    }
});

App.SpecialStuff.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [{
        "id": 79,
        "title": "fewfew",
        "body": "kkk",
        "modificators": [{
            "id": 1,
            "tpe": "vv",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "tpe": "mv",
        }]
    }]
});
App.SpecialStuffIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return this.store.find('special_stuff');
  }
});

App.Router.map(function () {
  // Add your routes here
  this.resource('specialStuff', function() {});
});

Ember.Inflector.inflector.uncountable('modificators');
Ember.Inflector.inflector.uncountable('special_stuff');
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Data's Fixture Adapter doesn't use a serializer for fetching data.  You're better off mocking json calls with something like https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax and using the rest adapter.

Here's some examples: [Ember-data embedded records current state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222457/ember-data-embedded-records-current-state/24224682#24224682)

Comment: Ho that's where I was close to thinking. Doesn't this make fixtures completely useless if you can't just put what your server would return?

Comment: It all depends on whether or not that adapter was created for the use of mimicking your server or just providing a way to insert fixtures into ember data easily. I don't know, personally if I'm trying to mimic what i plan on doing, I use the adapter and serializer i plan to use and mockjax.

Comment: Yes I guess I was taking Fixtures as a mocking only feature when it probably has other applications.
Thanks for the explanation!