# Ember data Embedded JSON without Id and no root object

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am working with Ember and Ember-data. But the JSON which i receive is not par with the Ember side-loading standards. The JSON does'nt have a root model. Also the models are embedded and some times haves Ids and sometimes does not have Id.

I have seen couple of links on how to add root model using **extract** hook and also how to play with embedded model using

```
App.ColorSerializer = DS.RestSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    foos: {embedded: 'always'}
  }
});
```

This code is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222457/ember-data-embedded-records-current-state) link.

This is the JSON used there

```
{
 colors:[
  {
    id: 1,
    color: "red",
    foos:[
      {
        id:1,
        name:'something 1'
      },
      {
        id:2,
        name:'something 2'
      }
    ]
  },
 ...
```

Now the problem that i am facing is that my JSON could also look like below(no root model "color")

```
{
    id: 1,
    color: "red",
    foos:[
      {
        id:1,
        name:'something 1'
      },
      {
        id:2,
        name:'something 2'
     }
  ]
},
...
```

or even like this(without Ids for foo objects)

```
{
    id: 1,
    color: "red",
    foos:[
      {
        name:'something 1'
      },
      {
        name:'something 2'
     }
  ]
},
...
```

Is there any way i can handle this? How do i add Ids to the embedded model foo? Also is there some solution/plugin which would accept any kind of embedded JSON and convert it into side loaded JSON and added Ids if needed.

I have seen [this](http://mozmonkey.com/2013/12/loading-json-with-embedded-records-into-ember-data-1-0-0-beta/) solution. Does it really work? Because it does not use the latest **EmbeddedRecordsMixin**

Answer (score 3):

I used a generic transform for arrays:

```
// /transforms/array.js
import DS from "ember-data";
import Ember from "ember";

export default DS.Transform.extend({
    deserialize: function (value) {
        if (Ember.isArray(value)) {
            return Ember.A(value);
        } else {
            return Ember.A();
        }
    },
    serialize: function (value) {
        if (Ember.isArray(value)) {
            return Ember.A(value);
        } else {
            return Ember.A();
        }
    }
});
```

Then in my model, I simply use:

```
foos: DS.attr("array")
```

Comment: That is quite a good approach and it makes sense as well. Also i would not be required to do many dirty work in the serializer unless to add the root object if that is missing. Thanks mate let me try this one